# How to fix Print Range in Rave Reports?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports

Print Range (From Page: x To Page: y) doesn't work, the printer always print all pages!
Any workaround or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevrona Support say that I have to upgrade my version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug from Rave Reports, and you should to upgrade to Rave Reports BE 5.02....
Here is a link (Rave Reports 5.02 for Delphi 7):
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25936

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to generate .pdf's always, and open the .pdf with an API call.